# How to fix "Unrecognized Vue directive" warning in Webstorm for Vue.js. Directive installed via npm and Vue.use

Tags: vue.js

How to fix "Unrecognized Vue directive" warning in Webstorm for Vue.js. Directive installed via npm and Vue.use

Answer (score 3):

The "Unrecognized Vue directive" warning seems to come from a bug from the IDE [documented here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52800/Vue3-directives-registered-through-the-plug-in-method-cannot-be-recognized).

Fixing the problem might be possible using a `web-types.json` file at the root of the project and adding the property `"web-types": "./web-types.json"` to the `package.json` file as explained in [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52800/Vue3-directives-registered-through-the-plug-in-method-cannot-be-recognized#focus=Comments-27-5617505.0-0). The Web-Types standard is a creation of JetBrains, the company behind WebStorm and PhpStorm, and is document in the [`JetBrains/web-types`](https://github.com/JetBrains/web-types) Github repository.

However in my case, using PhpStorm 2022.3.3, I was not able to fix the problem occurring with [Floating Vue](https://floating-vue.starpad.dev/) and the `v-tooltip` custom directive.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add property `"web-types": "./web-types.json"` to the package.json
2. Create file `web-types.json` at the root of the project with following:

```js
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "framework": "vue",
  "js-types-syntax": "typescript",
  "description-markup": "markdown",
  "framework-config": {
    "enable-when": {
      "file-extensions": [
        "vue"
      ]
    }
  },
  "contributions": {
    "html": {
      "vue-directives": [
        {
          "name": "ripple",
          "description": "",
          "doc-url": "",
          "attribute-value": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "required": false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

3. Replace ripple directive on your own.
4. Enjoy ;)